# eclipse where is args[] stored?

Tags: eclipse

i would like to know where does eclipse save entered args?(in which file?)
because these args that i entered -say- a month ago are remembered.

see snapshot:
[image: eclipse screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i'd suggest to save the launch config to a shared file in your project folder. you will find this option in the commons tab in your screenshot.

if you open it with a text-editor you will find following two tags

`<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.PROGRAM_ARGUMENTS" value="YOUR PROGRAM ARGUMENTS"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.VM_ARGUMENTS" value="YOUR VM ARGUMENTS"/>`

i also share my projects launch config in the company's scm.

Comment: this is very good suggestion, I also do it. To do it, in Common tab, Save as, choose 'Shared file'

Answer (score 0):

Search in the .metadata/plugins folder.  If you don't know, the .metadata folder is inside whatever folder you use as you workspace, and may be hidden.  Note that the "Launch Configuration" you're looking at there is saved as a convenience, and you can have multiple configurations.

Answer (score 0):

In your workspace's (not each project's) directory there is `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches` with an XML file for every launch configuration, and in there something like

```
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.PROGRAM_ARGUMENTS"
   value="123456789"/>
```

You should not need to go to the file, though, you can see and edit all this in the "Run > Run Configurations" dialog (the one in your screenshot).